# For every $R>0$, prove that there is a positive integer $n$ such that $1 + z + \frac {z^2}{2!} +...+\frac {z^n}{n!}$ has no zeros in $|z|<R$.

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

The problem is exactly that of the title.

I attempted to apply Rouché's theorem, by setting another function $f(z)=e^z$ and comparing the modulus of $f(z)$ and $f(z)-P_n (z)$ at the circle $|z|=R$, but I failed to proceed anymore.
Is my approach correct? Or is there another solution?

Comment: See the answer by lhf to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1769940)

Comment: Please include the question in the body of the post.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Why is that necessary?

Comment: @zhw, it's good practice on Math.SE to [make the body of the post self-contained](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/25695/5531).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R >0$. We know $\exp(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in B_R(0)$. So, there is an $M>0$ such that $|\exp(z)| \geq M > 0$ for all $z \in B_R(0)$. Now, there exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have
$$ \frac{M}{2}>|\exp(z)-P_n(z)| \geq ||\exp(z)|-|P_n(z)||,$$ and thus
$$ \frac{M}{2} > |\exp(z)|-|P_n(z)| > -\frac{M}{2}.$$

Therefore, 
$$ \frac{M}{2}+|\exp(z)| > |P_n(z)| > |\exp(z)|-\frac{M}{2}\geq \frac{M}{2} > 0$$
for all $n \geq N$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that exist $r>0 $such that $p_n$has zeros in $U:=\{|z|<r\} $.  Let $K\subset U$ compact. Prove that $p_n\to e^z$ over $K$ and obtain an absurd because $e^z$hasn't zeros